# не могу записать mp3 файл на sdcard

Tags: java, android

```
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

            System.out.println("Downloading");
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);

            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);


            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(root+"/"+list.get(con_position)+".mp3");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;


                output.write(data, 0, count);

            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        System.out.println("Downloaded");

        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

с манифестом все в порядке, в doInBackground передаю URL строку ресурса. Вроде трафик идет но не долго, следовательно никаких файлов нет, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Можете ваш Stack Trace скинуть? Или хотя бы что Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage()); выводит? Это очень важно.

Comment: Версия андройда какая? Если 6я то вы наверное забыли права на запись запросить у пользователя, начиная с 6ки некоторые права надо не только в манифесте отмечать, но и проверять их наличие пере собсно использованием и запрашивать если они ещё не предоставлены.

Comment: да, на девайсе 6 андроид, где об этом можно почитать?

Comment: Интересная ситуация, на эмуляторе 5.1.1 все работает, только куда музыку сохраняет до сих пор не понимаю

Comment: Ошибка есть? Предоставьте стектрейс, пожалуйста. Если нет - ищите файл

Comment: решил сделать все через Download manager, все отлично заработало